# NotImplementedError when creating new user from django admin page

Tags: django, admin

I created a custom user model and admin model and when I try to create a new user from admin,I got this error:

> NotImplementedError at /admin/account/myuser/add/

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/account/myuser/add/

Django Version: 2.2
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'account.apps.AccountConfig',
 'debug_toolbar']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py" in parse
  799.             handler = self.FUNC_MAP[sm_type]

During handling of the above exception ('UNKNOWN'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  606.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py" in add_view
  99.             return self._add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py" in _add_view
  126.         return super().add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in add_view
  1634.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1521.         with transaction.atomic(using=router.db_for_write(self.model)):

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py" in __enter__
  196.                 sid = connection.savepoint()

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in savepoint
  332.         self._savepoint(sid)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in _savepoint
  300.             cursor.execute(self.ops.savepoint_create_sql(sid))

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\sql\tracking.py" in execute
  186.         return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\sql\tracking.py" in _record
  124.             return method(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  99.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  67.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  76.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  82.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py" in execute
  53.             params)

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py" in __init__
  743.         self.parse()

File "C:\Users\hanan\Documents\GitHub\Predictive_maintenance\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py" in parse
  802.             raise NotImplementedError(f'{sm_type} command not implemented for SQL {self._sql}')

Exception Type: NotImplementedError at /admin/account/myuser/add/
Exception Value: UNKNOWN command not implemented for SQL SAVEPOINT "s5560_x1"
```

## This is my models.py

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
            if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, date_of_birth, password):

            user = self.create_user(email,
            password=password,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role= models.CharField(max_length=100)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']
```

## And my admin.py :

```
   from django import forms
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
    from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
    from account.models import MyUser

    class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
        """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
        fields, plus a repeated password."""
        password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
        password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

        class Meta:
            model = MyUser
            fields = ('email', 'date_of_birth')

        def clean_password2(self):
            password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
            if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
            return password2

        def save(self, commit=True):
            # Save the provided password in hashed format
            user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user

    class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
         password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

        class Meta:
            model = MyUser
            fields = ('email', 'password', 'date_of_birth', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

        def clean_password(self):
               return self.initial["password"]
    class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
        # The forms to add and change user instances
        form = UserChangeForm
        add_form = UserCreationForm

        # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
        # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
        # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
        list_display = ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'is_admin')
        list_filter = ('is_admin',)
        fieldsets = (
            (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
            ('Personal info', {'fields': ('date_of_birth',)}),
            ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
        )

        add_fieldsets = (
            (None, {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'password1', 'password2')}
            ),
        )
        search_fields = ('email',)
        ordering = ('email',)
        filter_horizontal = ()
    admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)
    admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

### Settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'pme5tk0(%744prm2jioq^y4h4$=8$_%n&sp)bhhvvi-8-z!a)n'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'account.apps.AccountConfig',
    'debug_toolbar',

]

#LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

######################### AUTH ############################

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.MyUser'

#AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('account.backends.CustomUserAuth',)

########################################################

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['C:/Users/hanan/Documents/GitHub/Predictive_maintenance/account/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'smtbdd',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':27017,

    }
}
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
)


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),  # Here you tell django to look for a folder named 'assets'
]
INTERNAL_IPS=['127.0.0.1']
```

When I changed this line: `admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)` to this line:  `admin.site.register(MyUser)`, I could create users but passwords are not hashed in the database.

### Update:The solution

The problem was not in the code but in django version,I just downgraded to Django version 2.1.8 (from 2.2) and the problem is fixed ;)

Comment: Could you post the full traceback?

Comment: Done, I edit the post and added the full traceback. I also want to inform you that I'm using Mongodb as bdd, I do not know if it has a relation with the error Thank's Jay.